# Ruby decrement to limit

Tags: ruby, methods, limit, increment, decrement

I'd like to have a set of methods that can increment/decrement a value, but with a lower limit of zero.

Basically:

```
def decrement
  @value -= 1
end
```

Except, I don't want it to go lower than zero.

What's the best "ruby way" to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def decrement
  @value -= 1 unless @value.zero?
end
```

Or if you'd like to throw an exception:

```
def decrement
  raise RangeError, "can't decrement below zero" if @value.zero?
  @value -= 1
end
```

Comment: This will fail if  `0 < value < 1`

Comment: Interesting point on the fail case... in this case I'm using integers so I can't hit that fail condition, can I?

Comment: Not if you're using integers. But you simply specified "a value" so I chose not to make assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

```
def decrement
  @value = [@value-1, 0].max
end
```

Comment: This is very clever, but not the most readable at first. However it does seem to avoid the fail case mentioned on yjerem's answer.

Comment: My guess is that its less efficient than your solution as well.  I always like providing alternative approaches anyways, since you never know when they might prove useful under different conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
def decrement(value)
  value -= 1 if value - 1 >= 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def decrement
  @value -= 1 unless @value - 1 < 0
end
```